# Are physicsy questions on-topic here?

Tags: discussion, physics.se

I'm seeing quite a few physicsy questions. Are they on topic here?

Examples:

[If nothing travels at the speed of light, except light, how can a black hole also pull light into itself?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/70/if-nothing-travels-at-the-speed-of-light-except-light-how-can-a-black-hole-als)

https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/69/does-e-equals-mc-squared-apply-to-a-black-hole

[Do all the objects in the universe exert force on all other objects?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/63/do-all-the-objects-in-the-universe-exert-force-on-all-other-objects)

Comment: This issue has been raised elsewhere, so I'm closing this as a duplicate to keep the discussion in one place.

Comment: Ah, somehow I didn't make the connection between physics and astrophysics. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Good question!

Yes, only if the physics is about the astromony! If you are trying to ask about speed of light in space, its OK!

Some questions might seem to be off-topic because of too low quality or too low searching for answer by the asker.

If you are trying to ask, define astronomy. It can be on-topic but the answer was an easy Google, so the community would downvote them! Or even flag them. So first search thoroughly then ask here!