# Questions Which Are Cosmological in Nature

Tags: discussion

There have been a number of posts so far discussing the scope of this astronomy SE site. Physics-y questions seem to be okay if the physics is directly related to astronomical/astrophysical objects ([Are physicsy questions on-topic here?](https://astronomy.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25/are-physicsy-questions-on-topic-here);[How to draw a line between Astrophysics and Physics, if there is any posibility?](https://astronomy.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6/how-to-draw-a-line-between-astrophysics-and-physics-if-there-is-any-posibility)).

My question pertains to cosmology. Do cosmological questions belong here or not? I would hope yes, but cosmology can sometimes be a bit more mathematical in nature. Additionally, it intersects with other branches of physics (namely particle physics, general relativity, etc..), which may or may not belong in an astronomy SE site. I'd be interested to hear opinions on this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Yes

If astronomers and astrophysics study such questions (and they do), ask your cosmology questions here.